# Remove Axis From Bar Chart

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bar-chart, series

I am making a bar chart that looks like this:

How do I remove the "Average Count" label seen in the upper left?[image]

See code below:

```
# Create a DataFrame for plotting
months = ["January", "Feburary", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
df = pd.DataFrame({'': months, 'Average Count': monthy_rentals})

# Plot the bar chart
ax = df.plot.bar(x="", y="Average Count", rot=30)
plt.ylabel("Average bike rentals")
plt.show()
```

Comment: `ax = df.plot.bar(x="", y="Average Count", rot=30, legend=False)`